# obtener información de un jsonb o json en postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

Tengo un campo en mi tabla el cual es un jsonb donde almaceno json como este(dejare un fragmento del json):

```
{

    "order": [
        {
            "notes": {
                "note": []
            },
            "onHold": "false",
            "wmnotes": {
                "wmnote": []
            },
            "invoices": {
                "invoiceDetail": []
            },
            "confirmed": "true",
            "enteredBy": "",
            "entryType": "",
            "orderType": "DTC",
            "orderEvent": "Update",
            "orderLines": {
                "orderLine": [
                    {
                        "notes": {
                            "note": []
                        },
                        "isGift": "false",
                        "itemID": "4027956",
                        "onHold": "false",
                        "wmnotes": {
                            "wmnote": [
                                {
                                    "noteSeq": "1",
                                    "noteCode": "",
                                    "noteType": "DDate",
                                    "visibility": "0",
                                    "commentText": "02/07/2019"
                                }
```

Lo que quiero es obtener la información de `wmnote` y devolverla como un jsonb o json, para esto cree una función pero me devuelve **`null`**.

Estaba viendo la documentación y he probado con `-->, ->, #>` pero solo puedo devolver la etiqueta padre con todos los valores.

> funcion postgreSQL:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION customer_orders.payments(d_id character 
  varying) RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$ declare 
 found_test jsonb; begin select o.info->'order'into found_test from 
customer_orders.order_json o where o.order_id = d_id; return (SELECT 
 json_build_array(jsonb_build_object('data',found_test))); end 
$function$
```

¿Me podrían ayudar con la query para obtener dicho dato en especifico?.

Saludos

Comment: puedes compartir la funcion que creaste para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION customer_orders.payments(d_id character varying)
 RETURNS jsonb
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$  
 declare
   found_test jsonb;
   
   
  begin

   select o.info->'order'into found_test
   from customer_orders.order_json o
   where o.order_id = d_id;
  
  
  return (SELECT json_build_array(jsonb_build_object('data',found_test)));
  end
 $function$
;
@IgmerRodriguez

Comment: te mencion que la estructura de tu JSON no esta bien

Comment: Deje un fragmento del json eso lo detalle en la publicacion, hay que cerrar sus llaves.
@IgmerRodriguez

Comment: Tu JSON esta en la Base de datos?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez si, la columna se llama info y es de tipo jsonb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo la query que me sirvio para obtener el tag "wmnote":`SELECT o.info->'order'->0 -> 'orderLines' -> 'orderLine' -> 0 -> 'wmnotes'->'wmnote'
FROM customer_orders o`